# Android - How to get calling Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

An `Activity` (SignInActivity) is calling a method in `FunkcjeAPI` which execute an `AsyncTask`.

My `AsyncTask` should show a `ProgressDialog` using an calling `Activity`. I don't know how to give it an correct `Activity` to the constructor. I tried a lot of thing, read a lot of tutorials and questions on SO, but I can't find solution. `FunkcjeAPI` isn't an Activity so I can't write `new Logowanie(this).execute(argumenty);`

---

`AsyncTask` calling code :

```
public class FunkcjeAPI {

    static String dozwrotu = null;

public static String zalogujSie(final String nick, final String haslo)
{
    String[] argumenty = {nick, haslo};
    new Logowanie(/* WHAT HERE ? */).execute(argumenty); // HELP ME IN THAT LINE !!!!!!!!!!!!!
    return dozwrotu;


}
```

My `AsyncTask` class code (it is in `FunkcjeAPI` class):

```
private class Logowanie extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        Activity wywolujaceActivity;

        public Logowanie(Activity wywolujaceActivity) {
            this.wywolujaceActivity = wywolujaceActivity;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            wywolujaceActivity.showDialog(SignInActivit.PLEASE_WAIT_DIALOG);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(final String... argi) {
            final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {     
            final String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://tymonradzik.pl/THUNDER_HUNTER/thapi.php?q=login&username=" + argi[0] + "&password=" + argi[1] + "&imei=");
            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject jObject;
                    try {

                        jObject = new JSONObject(json);
                        Log.wtf("Link", "http://tymonradzik.pl/THUNDER_HUNTER/thapi.php?q=login&username=" + argi[0] + "&password=" + argi[1] + "&imei=");
                        Log.wtf("Link", json);
                        String error = jObject.getString("error");
                        if(error == "You reached daily query limit !") { nadajWartosc("You reached daily query limit !"); }
                        if(error == "0") {nadajWartosc(jObject.getString("token"));}
                        if(error == "1") {nadajWartosc("1");}
                        if(error == "Invalid username") {nadajWartosc("Invalid username");}
                        if(error == "Invalid password") {nadajWartosc("Invalid password");}
                        if(error == "This user is already logged in !") {nadajWartosc("This user is already logged in !");}
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });   
                }}).start();
            return dozwrotu;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            wywolujaceActivity.removeDialog(SignInActivit.PLEASE_WAIT_DIALOG);

        }


    }
```

Comment: You can use getApplicationContext()

Comment: @TomerMor I wrote `Context.getApplicationContext()`, but then I see complier error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more parameter to `zalogujSie()` method that takes an `Activity`, and then use this parameter to start the AsyncTask:

```
public static String zalogujSie(Activity activity, final String nick, final String haslo)
{
    // .....
    new Logowanie(activity).execute(argumenty); 
    return dozwrotu;
}
```

Then you would call this method from the activity like this:

```
FunkcjeAPI.zalogujSie(this, "Nick", "Haslo");
```

Comment: It doesn't work : I see that error `No enclosing instance of type FunkcjeAPI is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type FunkcjeAPI (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of FunkcjeAPI).`

Comment: The error you are getting is comming from something else, not because `Activity` parameter was added. Most probably you are using incorrect inner classes.

Comment: Declare the `Logowanie` class as a static class: `private static class Logowanie{ ... }`.